# for_in loop for nested object javascript don't return expected values

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I am trying to walk through a JS object, with the for_in loop.
That seems to be returning the found value (contentCard1) as plain text. 
I can't get it to print val.text

```
var contentCards = {
    contentCard1: {text: "text in here", date: "date in here"}
}

for(var val in contentCards) {
    console.log(val.text);
}
```

Logging `val.text` gives me `undefined`, and logging just `val` gives me `contentCard1`.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of *that* question, though obviously there is overlap.

Comment: @nnnnnn My apologies. :-) Would still hold the vote as dupe answers how to loop over nested object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), you are iterating over the keys of `contentCards`. For the access you need the object and the key with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
contentCards[val].text
//          ^^^^^
```

```js
var contentCards = { contentCard1: { text: "text in here", date: "date in here" } };

for (var val in contentCards) {
    console.log(contentCards[val].text);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this:

```
 var contentCards = {
            contentCard1: { text: "text in here", date: "date in here" }
        }

     alert(contentCards.contentCard1.text);
```

Comment: Huh? What's the point of a loop if you don't use the iterator variable and instead directly access a specific nested property?

Comment: yes. but i think you have  contentCards as list

Comment: Again, if you have `val in contentCards` and then never use `val`, what's the point of the loop? Every iteration would alert the same, specific value.